# error occurs when I use you-get project on Github

Tags: python

I wanted to use you-get to download videos, but when I use it after I installed it, an error ocurred:

my python3.9 is well installed and I have checked the system path. I have also used many ways to install you-get including using pip3, downloading the zip from github and this error always occur. I thought this problem could be caused by my vpn, but when I close vpn, nothing changed.

I opened cmd with administrator as well.

I typed this command:   you-get 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWQwrU1qUrc' --debug

```
[DEBUG] get_location: http://'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWQwrU1qUrc'
[DEBUG] get_location: http://'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWQwrU1qUrc'

you-get: version 0.4.1500, a tiny downloader that scrapes the web.
you-get: Namespace(version=False, help=False, info=False, url=False, json=False, no_merge=False, no_caption=False, force=False, skip_existing_file_size_check=False, format=None, output_filename=None, output_dir='.', player=None, cookies=None, timeout=600, debug=True, input_file=None, password=None, playlist=False, auto_rename=False, insecure=False, http_proxy=None, extractor_proxy=None, no_proxy=False, socks_proxy=None, stream=None, itag=None, URL=["'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWQwrU1qUrc'"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in do_open
  h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in request
  self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
  self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
  self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
  self.send(msg)
File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 950, in send
  self.connect()
File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 921, in connect
  self.sock = self._create_connection(
File "C:\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 822, in create_connection
  for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
File "C:\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
  for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\you_get-0.4.1500-py3.9.egg\you_get\common.py", line 1777, in url_to_module
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\you_get-0.4.1500 py3.9.egg\you_get\common.py", line 393, in get_location
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\you_get-0.4.1500-py3.9.egg\you_get\common.py", line 408, in urlopen_with_retry
File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
  result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1375, in http_open
  return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1349, in do_open
  raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in do_open
  h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in request
  self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
  self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
  self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
  self.send(msg)
File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 950, in send
  self.connect()
File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 921, in connect
  self.sock = self._create_connection(
File "C:\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 822, in create_connection
  for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
File "C:\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
  for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python39\Scripts\you-get-script.py", line 33, in <module>
  sys.exit(load_entry_point('you-get==0.4.1500', 'console_scripts', 'you-get')())
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\you_get-0.4.1500-py3.9.egg\you_get\__main__.py", line 92, in main
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\you_get-0.4.1500-py3.9.egg\you_get\common.py", line 1798, in main
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\you_get-0.4.1500-py3.9.egg\you_get\common.py", line 1680, in script_main
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\you_get-0.4.1500-py3.9.egg\you_get\common.py", line 1327, in download_main
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\you_get-0.4.1500-py3.9.egg\you_get\common.py", line 1788, in any_download
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\you_get-0.4.1500-py3.9.egg\you_get\common.py", line 1779, in url_to_module
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\you_get-0.4.1500-py3.9.egg\you_get\common.py", line 393, in get_location
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\you_get-0.4.1500-py3.9.egg\you_get\common.py", line 408, in urlopen_with_retry
File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
  result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1375, in http_open
  return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1349, in do_open
  raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

could someone help me pls, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're intent on using cmd, you should replace `'` with `"` in your command, or since the website contains no spaces anyway, just remove the quotes. So try running:

```
you-get "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWQwrU1qUrc"
OR
you-get https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWQwrU1qUrc
```

However in the future I'd suggest you just use Windows PowerShell it's much better in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you so much, I cannot believe I made a such stupid mistake. This is my first time to ask questions on stackoverflow, and I'm surprised that there are people who are so helpful and willing to answer my questions.

Comment: No problem, yeah most people on here just wanna help